# Handling an end of file error causing core dump

Tags: c++, c

The issue at hand, when the file reading routine reaches the end of file row, it causes crash of my program due to core dump. It is precisely at the end of the file when this happens.

What is a good practice way to continue the program after finishing the end of line.

Here is what i did

```
std::string rd_file(std::string fname,uint16_t lnum)
{
  ifstream PTS_file;
  std::string line;
  uint16_t lcnt=0; 
  PTS_file.open(fname);
  if (!PTS_file.is_open())
  {
       cout<<" File "<<fname<<" is not found "<<endl;

  }
  else if (PTS_file.eof())
  {
       cout<< " End of file data..."<<endl;
  }
  else 
  {
    while(!PTS_file.eof() && lcnt <=lnum)
    {
          getline(PTS_file,line);
          lcnt++;
          if ( lcnt == lnum)
          {
             PTS_file.close();
             return line;
          }

     }

   }

 }
```

This function when it reaches an end of line , causes core dump....what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I think this need not be tagged `c`.

Answer (score 3):

If your function ever reaches the end of the function, there will be problems since you don't have a return statement. That by itself is cause for undefined behavior.

Change the function a little bit so that you have a valid `return` statement at the end.

```
std::string rd_file(std::string fname,uint16_t lnum)
{
   ifstream PTS_file;
   std::string line;
   uint16_t lcnt=0; 
   PTS_file.open(fname);
   if (!PTS_file.is_open())
   {
      cout<<" File "<<fname<<" is not found "<<endl;
   }
   else if (PTS_file.eof())
   {
      cout<< " End of file data..."<<endl;
   }
   else 
   {
      // This block is refactored and simplified.
      while (lcnt < lnum && std::getline(PTS_file,line) )
      {
         lcnt++;
      }
   }

   return line;
}
```

**PS** You don't need to explicitly call `close()` on `PTS_file`. The destructor will take care of that.

Comment: also suggest using `while(getline`... instead of `while(eof`, as the latter means that the last line may be garbled/repeated

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the lnum supposed to be the line at which the reading is done, that is why it is an argument of the function. Say, i want to read only line 23 of a file . The while loop you proposed doesn't have the condition to getline 23 (lnum)

Comment: @SamGomari, the conditional of the `while` loop makes sure that you return the 23-rd line of the file if there are 23 or more lines in the file. If there are less than 23 lines, you will end up returning the last line of the file. If that is not acceptable, you will need to add a check at the end and return whatever makes sense for your application. E.g. `if ( lcnt < lnum ) return string();` will return an empty string.

Comment: @RSahu  actually my code works, it happened that the error was due to something else. Thanks R Sahu.